# how to draw a straight line between two point on google maps in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps, google-maps-flutter

I am using code below to draw but its not working

```
 polyline = Polyline(
  polylineId: polylineId,
  color: Colors.red,
  width: 5,
  jointType: JointType.round,
  points:  latLongList,
);
  _mapPolylines[polylineId] = polyline;
```

Output is red line but i need blue line as output

[image: Output is red line but i need blue line as output]

Comment: You just need to remove all other coordinates from your latLongList and pass only the initial and destination coordinates. Are you doing this already?

Comment: I solved the issue. Issue was due to duplicate coordinates as i am using live location tracker to update the polylines. Adding coordinates with specific minimum distance between previous coordinate and new coordinate solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. Issue was due to duplicate coordinates as i am using live location tracker to update the polylines. Adding coordinates with specific minimum distance between previous coordinate and new coordinate solved my issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hey can you help me with this?